# Best Practices: Application Pool Identity Account

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

What's the best practices to configure Application Pool Identity account? Is it acceptable to use "Network Service" account on a hosting server? What privileges shall I assign that Identity Account when I add it to SQL Server DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best practice I follow is that of granting the account the minimum privileges necessary to do its job.  This is the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

Comment: The hosting server is a public internet server. Thanks for the links, they are more theoretical than practical. Thanks